# What effect does conversion have on mash temp

Tags: mash

We're mashing our second batch (after a year of extract) and seems like we cannot keep the mash temp low enough.  We struck at 165F in an attempt to hit 152 for mash (grain was at 65F).  We saw a higher temp at first (~156) so we left the cooler open for a bit until we hit ~150F (lower than we wanted), but after closing the lid, the temp creeped back up to 156 range.
so the Q: is, where is the energy coming from?  Is conversion adding that much energy to the mash?

Comment: You can always add cold water to reduce the mash temperature, as well. As mentioned; making sure you stir the mash so all the temperature is distributed evenly is paramount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not "gaining energy".  You're just not distributing the energy that's there well enough.  Keep stirring the mash until you get the same temp at any location or depth.  Conversion is definitely not adding energy.

Comment: Thanks, Denny.  I'm using your batch sparge method. Just having trouble working out the bugs. Next question might be on calculating mash& sparge volume better.  Current methods not working too well

Comment: The easy way..mash with whatever ratio you like...these days I'm around 1.6 qt./lb.  After you run off your mash, measure how much you've got.  Subtract that from the amount you want to boil.  The answer you get is how much sparge water to use.